# Why do QAbstractLight's methods no longer work in PySide6?

Tags: python, qt3d, pyside6

In `PySide2` `QAbstractLight`'s methods: `setIntensity()` and `setColor()` were working correctly, but for some reason, in `PySide6` these methods are not changing underlying shader. No error messages are shown when these methods are used and these attributes are actually retrievable with `intensity()` and `color()` methods but these changes have no impact on the rendered result. For some reason these attributes are not passed to the shader. What has changed in `Qt3D` so this is the case?

**Minimal working example:**
[PySide2 Qt3D mesh does not show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60585973/pyside2-qt3d-mesh-does-not-show-up)
. If You try this example and change color from `"white"` to `"red"` it will work, but if You change imports from `PySide2` to `PySide6` and leave all the code intact color will still remain `"white"`. Method `setColor("red")` is ignored. Same with `intensity`. It is also ignored

Comment: I think it is a Qt6 bug since I have made the change that you indicate in the official example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt3d-basicshapes-cpp-example.html, and I reproduce the error that you indicate. I recommend you report it.